# Finding a solution to the recurrence relation $T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence relation $$T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n .$$ I know that I cannot use Master's theorem here and by intuition I can see the relation will be of order $O(n^2)$.

But how to solve it, I have tried iterative method which was futile. Please help.

Comment: Is n^2 a mistyped n-2? Otherwise, since $n^2\geq n$, how can you say that this is a _recurrence_ relation?

Comment: @AndreasT Sorry its n/2 not n^2.

Comment: Then what about odd $n$?

Comment: @AndreasT Does it really matter, if the question would have been T(n) = T(n/2) + n then I would have used iterative method and get T(n) = n + n/2 +n/4 . . . n/n and I would eventually get T(n) = $n(1− {1/2}^{log_2n+1})/(1-1/2)$ = 2n-1, which takes care of odd and even numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(n)=T(n-1)+T\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)+n$

$T(n)-T(n-1)-T\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)=n$

Getting the particular solution part is very easy.

Let $T_p(n)=An+B$ ,

Then $An+B-(A(n-1)+B)-\left(\dfrac{An}{2}+B\right)\equiv n$

$-\dfrac{An}{2}+A-B\equiv n$

$\therefore\begin{cases}-\dfrac{A}{2}=1\\A-B=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}A=-2\\B=-2\end{cases}$

$\therefore T_p(n)=-2n-2$

But getting the complementary solution part is quite difficult.

Since we should handle the equation $T_c(n)-T_c(n-1)-T_c\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)=0$ .

Let $T_c(n)=\int_0^\infty2^{nt}K(t)~dt$ ,

Then $\int_0^\infty2^{nt}K(t)~dt-\int_0^\infty2^{(n-1)t}K(t)~dt-\int_0^\infty2^{\frac{nt}{2}}K(t)~dt=0$

$\int_0^\infty2^{-nt}K(t)~dt-\int_0^\infty2^{nt}2^{-t}K(t)~dt-\int_0^\infty2^{nt}K(2t)~d(2t)=0$

$\int_0^\infty((1-2^{-t})K(t)-2K(2t))2^{nt}~dt=0$

$\therefore(1-2^{-t})K(t)-2K(2t)=0$

$K(2t)=\dfrac{1-2^{-t}}{2}K(t)$

Let $\begin{cases}t=2^u\\K(t)=F(u)\end{cases}$ ,

Then $F(u+1)=\dfrac{1-2^{-2^u}}{2}F(u)$

$F(u)=\dfrac{\prod\limits_{s=0}^\infty(1-2^{-2^u2^s})}{2^u}$

$K(t)=\dfrac{\prod\limits_{s=0}^\infty(1-2^{-t2^s})}{t}$

$\therefore T_c(n)=C\int_0^\infty\dfrac{2^{nt}\prod\limits_{s=0}^\infty(1-2^{-t2^s})}{t}dt$

Comment: "Getting the particular solution part is very easy." "But getting the particular solution part is very difficult."

Comment: @ricky: Sorry about the typo. I have been modified.

Comment: It's a fantastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n$,
it looks to me that $T(n)$ grows quite quickly.

Suppose that $T$ is smooth
and $T(n) \approx a n^b + O(n^{b-1})$.
Then $T(n-1) = a(n-1)^b + O((n-1)^{b-1})
= an^b -abn^{b-1} + O(n^{b-1})
= an^b + O(n^{b-1})
$
so
$an^b+O(n^{b-1})
=an^b + O(n^{b-1})+a(n/2)^b + O(n/2)^{b-1}+n
$
or
$a(n/2)^b=O(n^{b-1})
$
which is never true.
So, in this case, $T(n)-T(n-1)$
is smaller than $T(n/2)$.

Arguing the other way,
if $T$ grows exponentially,
$T(n) \approx a b^n$,
then
$T(n)-T(n-1)
\approx ab^n - ab^{n-1}
=a(b-1)b^{n-1}$
and this is larger than $T(n/2)$.

So, unless I have made a mistake
(p > .37),
$T$ has a growth between powers
and exponential.
Maybe something like $b^{n^c}$
where $0 < c < 1$
or $b^{n/\ln n}$.